Loop through variables to filter a tibble in R
This feels like it should be easier than it is but here we go. I have a data frame that looks like this:
to.csv = structure(list(geography = c("030223131022122122", "030223131220201023", 
"030223131023121330", "030223131212130201", "030223131202323120", 
"030223131202033333", "030223131202003223", "030223131200111131", 
"030223131032003101", "030223131020030220"), xlon = c(-79.403, 
-79.44008, -79.30138, -79.20937, -79.39201, -79.40987, -79.44008, 
-79.36592, -79.2588, -79.43047), xlat = c(43.87067, 43.67234, 
43.87562, 43.75076, 43.71305, 43.73985, 43.75572, 43.83205, 43.88948, 
43.93895), bounds = c("-79.40369,43.87018,-79.40231,43.87117", 
"-79.44077,43.67184,-79.43939,43.67284", "-79.30206,43.87513,-79.30069,43.87612", 
"-79.21005,43.75027,-79.20868,43.75126", "-79.39270,43.71256,-79.39133,43.71355", 
"-79.41055,43.73935,-79.40918,43.74034", "-79.44077,43.75523,-79.43939,43.75622", 
"-79.36661,43.83155,-79.36523,43.83255", "-79.25949,43.88899,-79.25812,43.88998", 
"-79.43115,43.93845,-79.42978,43.93944"), start_date = c("2021-07-01", 
"2021-07-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-07-01", 
"2021-07-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-07-01"), end_date = c("2021-07-31", 
"2021-07-31", "2021-07-31", "2021-07-31", "2021-07-31", "2021-07-31", 
"2021-07-31", "2021-07-31", "2021-07-31", "2021-07-31"), agg_day_period = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), agg_time_period = c(20L, 
22L, 20L, 6L, 14L, 22L, 7L, 16L, 21L, 7L), activity_index_total = c(0.018224, 
0.020511, 0.070478, 0.054159, 0.037204, 0.036961, 0.046656, 0.415398, 
0.017664, 0.029587)), row.names = c(770468L, 955885L, 621962L, 
1164473L, 479957L, 588295L, 61790L, 1338380L, 1225032L, 688909L
), class = "data.frame")

I want to create filtered data frames by subsetting hours that represent different times of data. Here are two examples:
wd_1_5 <- c(1:5)
wd_6_9 <- c(6:9)

I want to loop through a whole bunch of these and filter my tibble, which I then plan on turning into rasters. How can I do this in a loop? Or is there a more effective way to do this?
Here's what I've been currently trying:
time.periods < c(wd_1_5, wd_6_9)

for(i in time.periods){
  df = to.csv %>%
    filter(agg_day_period == 1, agg_time_period %in% i) %>%
    group_by(geography, bounds)
  
  print(unique(df$agg_time_period))
}


What is the use of to.csv here for?

Provided example df and to.csv are the same thing? Can you provide a desired output, based on your example data? It seems to result with an empty data frame.

Updated to clarify data frame name inconsistency

So you're example will always net no results, as there are no conditions by which agg_day_period == 1 and agg_time_period will be in the sets you provided for sequences of hours. That said, you could take the approach of writing a wrapper function and then mapping over the sequences, example:

.f <- function(range_of_hours = NULL, data = df, ...){
    df %>% filter(
        agg_day_period == 1, 
        as.numeric(agg_time_period) %in% range_of_hours
      ) %>% group_by(geography, bounds)
}

> seq_hours <- list(1:5, 6:9, 10:15, 16:30)

> Map(function(i){
    slice_of_data <- .f(i)
    #insert whatever function you want that 
    #rasterizes/stores the grouped records that met condition here

}, seq_hours)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 0 × 9
# Groups:   geography, bounds [0]
# ℹ 9 variables: geography <chr>, xlon <dbl>, xlat <dbl>, bounds <chr>, start_date <chr>, end_date <chr>,
#   agg_day_period <int>, agg_time_period <int>, activity_index_total <dbl>

[[2]]
# A tibble: 0 × 9
# Groups:   geography, bounds [0]
# ℹ 9 variables: geography <chr>, xlon <dbl>, xlat <dbl>, bounds <chr>, start_date <chr>, end_date <chr>,
#   agg_day_period <int>, agg_time_period <int>, activity_index_total <dbl>

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 × 9
# Groups:   geography, bounds [1]
  geography           xlon  xlat bounds                start_date end_date agg_day_period agg_time_period activity_index_total
  <chr>              <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                 <chr>      <chr>             <int>           <int>                <dbl>
1 030223131202323120 -79.4  43.7 -79.39270,43.71256,-… 2021-07-01 2021-07…              1              14               0.0372

[[4]]
# A tibble: 6 × 9
# Groups:   geography, bounds [6]
  geography           xlon  xlat bounds                start_date end_date agg_day_period agg_time_period activity_index_total
  <chr>              <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                 <chr>      <chr>             <int>           <int>                <dbl>
1 030223131022122122 -79.4  43.9 -79.40369,43.87018,-… 2021-07-01 2021-07…              1              20               0.0182
2 030223131220201023 -79.4  43.7 -79.44077,43.67184,-… 2021-07-01 2021-07…              1              22               0.0205
3 030223131023121330 -79.3  43.9 -79.30206,43.87513,-… 2021-07-01 2021-07…              1              20               0.0705
4 030223131202033333 -79.4  43.7 -79.41055,43.73935,-… 2021-07-01 2021-07…              1              22               0.0370
5 030223131200111131 -79.4  43.8 -79.36661,43.83155,-… 2021-07-01 2021-07…              1              16               0.415 
6 030223131032003101 -79.3  43.9 -79.25949,43.88899,-… 2021-07-01 2021-07…              1              21               0.0177









This will create a list with elements named wd_1_5 and wd_6_9 and element values that are filtered tibbles:
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

agg_time_values <- list(wd_1_5 = 1:5, wd_6_9 = 6:9)

map(agg_time_values, \(i) filter(df, agg_day_period == 1, agg_time_period %in% i))

